# Inhibit grub on multiboot with UEFI and GPT

Tags: boot, grub, uefi

I'm running a multiboot laptop with GPTs. The OS'es include Windows, Fedora, Debian and Ubuntu.

Each distro tries to control booting the computer, but each has its own little quirks. For example, two distro's grub misses Windows (can't boot to it), another distro's grub misses Fedora (can't boot to it), and yet another distro's grub misses Debian (can't boot to it).

It does not matter how many times I clean up `/boot` and then issue `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` on the current OS and other distros. The problem persists.

The way I've found to boot into each OS without the issue is to use the UEFI's loader. But if I use the firmware's loader, I found it still takes me to a grub menu with broken entries.

How do I disable the probing for grub menu entries so that each distro's flavor of grub only finds itself and no others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probing that each OS's GRUB does is controlled *before* the system boots by files in `/etc/grub.d`. In particular, there's usually a script called `30_os-prober` that controls the OS-probing process. This is likely to be quite intimidating to configure, though. You'll need to run `update-grub` or `grub-mkconfig` after adjusting the probing script in order to create a new configuration file.

There's a tool called GRUB Customizer that's supposed to greatly simplify such procedures. It's described [here,](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134) among other places. I've never used it myself, so I can't provide more details directly, but it might be worth investigating.

Another option is to ditch GRUB in favor of [another EFI boot loader for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) My own [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is likely to be relatively easy to set up and configure, since it scans for kernels at boot time, and so doesn't need to be reconfigured whenever you install a new kernel. The biggest caveat is that with four OSes/distributions installed, your menu will initially be quite cluttered, including three separate GRUB entries. You'll therefore need to clean it up by editing `refind.conf`, uncommenting the `dont_scan_dirs` line, and adding entries to keep those multiple GRUB entries out of the listing. You'll also probably want to adjust the icons, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#hiding) You could still end up with too many kernel entries for comfort; that's best handled by uninstalling unused kernels via your distributions' package managers. You may need to run `mkrlconf.sh` (a script that comes with rEFInd) in each distribution to create a `/boot/refind_linux.conf` file, although that's sometimes not strictly necessary.